# C compiled programs that don't work in my Windows 10

Tags: python, c++, c, windows

At the beginning I installed Visual Studio 2015 community edition, writing simple C or C++ program. I compile them without errors, but when I run the exes (both from the `cmd` or clicking on the file) the process gets frozen. 
I reinstalled Visual Studio and then removed it.

I tried Code Block with MinGW but the same; my C programs freeze the terminal.
Now I installed Cygwin and I have the same problem, but just for test I used Python and Python works.

My last hypothesis is to format the PC, but I would avoid it. I thought that it was a gcc compatibility problem, but it cannot be, because Visual Studio is different from it and obviously should give no error to me.

P.S 
The file permissions allow the read and the execution.

Comment: Are you running avast antivirus?

Comment: Would you mind showing us the freezing program?

Comment: Maybe the problem is in your program. Just saying...

Comment: Having anti-virus software installed on your programming PC is very counter-productive and will only cause problems. More problems than most viruses would manage to cause, actually.

Comment: Yes i run avast.
I am going to try to disable it, also if other times he locked some programs and I have been able to see and unlock this

Answer (score 1):

I cannot believe it!!
Other times Avast locked my apps and I could see it and unlock them.
But not now, not now because my brother(only him can be) disabled the notification on avast putting his in silent mode.

I feel so stupid! Thank you.